# Why is ES not returning records matching a double field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query in ES:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered" : {
      "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "someStringField:some-alpha-num-value"
        }
      },
      "filter" : {
        "term" : {
          "_type" : "TypeOfEntity"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size" : 5
}
```

It returns to me a set of hits, some of which have a `someDoubleField` that is equal to 0.

However, I get no results when I change the `query_string` like this:

```
"query_string" : {
     "query" : "someDoubleField:0 AND someStringField:some-alpha-num-value"
}
```

I have multiple indexes in ES. When I change the index to a different one, I start getting multiple hits. Both the indexes have the same mapping and same set of documents.

What could be the problem here? I'd be happy to provide additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if index and type are correct while querying on ES.

Comment: Thanks! It worked after I added the 'Type' of mapping in the ES URL.

Comment: I've asked about this answer in [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345854/add-option-to-handle-the-review-of-an-answer-by-flagging-the-question)